# What are the Examples of good karmas according to Hindu scriptures?

Tags: karma

The law of karma , according to Hinduism , decides all the fruits of actions we are to receive in our births and lives. So what are the actions that one can perform to develop good karmas in life according to various Hindu scriptures? Thank you

Comment: I am not sure if this will be answer but I want to narrate one small instance of mahabharata:

when Duryodhana and Arjuna come to Sri Krishna to seek his blessings before the start of war, Arjuna humbly choose Krishna's guidance and giving away Krishna's army to Duryodhana who feared losing the army to Arjuna. There are many more instances which give us an idea of living humble life, respecting elders(Arjuna respect towards Krishna, Yudhishthira, bhishma, drona), seeking enlightenment from guru(Krishnarjuna samvada) are basic karmas we can follow in our day to day life